# Where do I put the "require '/.alchemyapi'" in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require, alchemy

I've used "require '/.alchemyapi'" in a pure Ruby program to test the response of an API, now I'm ready to use it in my Rails application.  The problem is, I don't know where or how to incorporate it within my application.  Where am I supposed to put the "require '/.alchemyapi'" statement?  Note, this has NO gem associated with it.  Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: I meant to say I've used "require './alchemyapi'" in a pure Ruby program.

Comment: You can do it in `config/application.rb`, as described here:  [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Ruby codes in `lib` folder, and require it like this:

`require "#{RAILS.root}/lib/yourcode.rb`

just like the suggestion made by Dan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174377/ruby-rails-how-to-create-a-class-and-access-it-from-the-controller). You can also put your code in another custom directory of your preference and have it accessible from anywhere by manipulating `config.load_paths` like the answer provided by Katz [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You can put `require` statement into `config/application.rb` file for rails application.